# Why distance between source images in Michelson interferometer experiment is twice the distance between two mirrors

Tags: interference, interferometry

In the Michelson interferometer experiment, there are two mirrors which are perpendicular to each other. When we see in telescope, we see one mirror, let's name it (a), directly and one mirror as image, let's name it as (b).

Q(1) Every book says that when there is distance d between (a) and (b), then there is  2d distance between two images of source created by (a) and (b). I don't get how there is 2d distance.

Q(2) Also every book shows following diagram saying source and (a) and (b) CAN be taken in one line. Why they are taking source in line with the two? Are they taking the source in line because when we stand in front of plane mirror, we see our image in line with object and due to that similarity source CAN be taken in line with the two.[image]

Image has been taken from Optics by Eugene Hecht.
Sorry for my poor English.

Or perhaps suggest some book which talks from scratch.

Comment: 2d comes from the fact that the image has travelled to and from the mirror, thus doubling the distance between them.

Comment: Sir, can u please make it more clear thru any image or anything else which u thunk i am missing, if u can please neme some reference book or topic name so that i can look it in my local language book of physics

Comment: Sir, are u talking about the fact that when object moves towards a stationary mirror then image has to travel with twice the speed of object. Or are u talking about something else?

Comment: Does 2d come from geometrical calculations?

Comment: The signal is split in an interferometer, and the interference between the two copies are measured, where one of the copiues have experienced a path difference (moving mirror). The signal has to go from the beamsplitter to the mirror and then back again to recombine with the unaltered signal, thus it travels to AND from the mirror, making the distance travelled 2d.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but here is a figure I made for my optics lessons on this topic. It's a purely geometrical result. The source is $S$, then:

- $S'$ is the image of $S$ through the beam splitter $S_{p}$
- $S_{1}'$ is the image of $S'$ through mirror $M_{1}$
- $S_{2}'$ is the image of $S'$ through $M_{2}$', which is the image of mirror $M_{2}$ through the beam splitter

If $e$ is the distance between $M_{1}$ and $M_{2}'$, then distance between $S_{1}'$ and $S_{2}'$ is $2 e$. Hope it helps.

Edit: the light rays in the figure aren't necessary for this proof, I only left them for clarity.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In an interferometer, the object (a light source) is not moving. Light from the source is split by a half- silvered mirror into two beams (one at a right angle to the other). Each goes out to a flat mirror and is reflected back to the half-silvered mirror which recombines them into one. In a flat mirror, the image distance is equal to the object distance, which gives you factor of 2.  In order to maintain coherence with a normal light source, the length of the two beams must be about the same. If one of the flat mirrors is moved (along the path of its beam), you see a shift in the interference pattern. With ideal alignment, a circular pattern expands or contracts.